How do I make a procedural texture fit into a mask with seamless edges?
I've created a procedural noise texture in Blender's shader editor (fig 1), as well as a mask which, using 2 gradient textures (fig 2), contains the noise only to the central part of the mesh. (fig 3)

The noise's colour ramp means that the edges of the noise blend to a darker orange colour, but where the mask's edge is, the noise is sharply cut off without the same fade to dark. (fig 4)

Is there some way to preserve the noise and mask as they appear now, but to somehow make blender apply the colour ramp to the whole noise within the mask so that it similarly blends from yellow to orange like the noise in the center of the mask? (fig 5 - illustrated roughly in GIMP)

The texture is intended to be animated, so simply painting the effect in is not possible.
Here is my node tree: the top part is the noise and colour ramp. Below that is a copy of the noise texture which is used with the gradients below that to limit the mask to the central part of the mesh.

Thank you to those who take the time to read this, and for any who can help me understand how to do what I'm after.

Mask the noise before color ramp.

You need to make the mask affect the noise itself, so the gradient of the mask will become a gradient in the noise.
(I had to use an "add" because the ramps are inverted, usually we use a multiply for that, it's easier to understand, but then both ramps should grow to the right)

Result:


Just to avoid any doubt, the gradients I used got white outside, just like yours.


Thanks for your response. The result you have look just like what I need, but there are some issues. I have followed your node set up precisely, but I am having a strange issue where most of the colours are getting masked out leaving the end result looking nothing like the original noise in my question pictures.
Edit: Never mind, my bad! Seems that I forgot to change the threshold value on the Greater Than math node. Everything appears to be working as it should, and as I'd like! Thank you very much for your help!
